# In Excel, How to Exclude a list of Values in COUNTIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

This is giving me a huge number

=SUM(COUNTIF(A3:A777,{"<>*United Kingdom";"<>*France";"<>*United states";"<>*Germany";"<>*Switzerland";;"<>*Estonia";"?*"}))

Also, is there a more efficiënter way, If I want to change or add values the list in the future

Comment: please check this information and then update your question. Thanks [Help Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering)

Comment: What exactly do you want to count? You are now checking each cell in `A3:A777` against an array of values of which probably n-1 elements in the array will be true. This will lead up to a very large number.

Comment: I'd do a count of all of them, then subtract the ones that **do** match the criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to switch to an `MMULT` construction when dealing with multiple 'not-equal-to' conditions:

`=SUM(N(MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(CountryList),A3:A777))),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(CountryList),,,0))=0))`

where *CountryList* is a **vertical** range which comprises the list of values to exclude.

Comment: Im sorry, Im a novice with excel. Where would I put, lets say, France into the formula?

Comment: You wouldn't. France would form part of the *CountryList* Named Range, which, as stated, should comprise a vertical range within a worksheet somewhere. Much easier to maintain and more dynamic if you set it up that way, rather than including your list of countries within the actual formula.